# CSS or JavaScript Div Blur magic

Tags: javascript, css, icloud, blurry

Okay, so a new version of the iCloud website is out. It has what appears to be some crazy voodoo Apple magic going on. They were able to blur the background icons behind the login screen, and I can't figure out how they did it. It's not a static image, as the icons change size if you resize the browser.

Would someone please explain?

https://www.icloud.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can implement using css! please check out

http://www.w3schools.com/svg/svg_fegaussianblur.asp

You can use alot of different filters by declaring them like

```
<filter id="f1" x="0" y="0">
      <feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" stdDeviation="15" />
</filter>
```

these can be black and white filters, cyanotype etc. From there just reference it on the object using filter='url(#f1)'

EDIT

CAN BE DONE USING BLUR CSS

http://jsfiddle.net/SvH6w/6/

Comment: But, how do I make it where the divs bellow one div are blurred? I don't want to have to apply it to each element... and it should work for text too.

Comment: Hey sorry for the slow response -> please see this i think its what you're looking for!

Comment: CSS filter: blur; is what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

You could possibly do it using [BlurJs](http://www.blurjs.com/) , check out the demo: http://www.blurjs.com/simpledemo.html

Comment: does that affect all DIV contents, or just an image?

Comment: all div contents, you specify the div and call blurjs() on it.

Answer (score 0):

They are using a canvas and sets it as a background image

```
/* from the page: */
background-image: -webkit-canvas(blurredDerivativeForButtonsc245);
```

you can do all the blurring on the canvas content.